# nodeJS server slow and jerky performance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

Using nodeJS and socket.io as an excercise
I built a prototype of a mouse cursor, controlled by an iphone, 
that moves on the browser viewport. 
that's it. it works, but the performance is really bad. the cursor is jerky, chopped...it doesnt move smoothly...as I see in my terminal the emission and sometimes it gets stuck...

I was thinking of using something like code below, but is still way from being optimal..

```
setInterval(function() {
   socket.emit('sendposition', x, y);
}, 25);
```

I wonder if thatere is any best practice to improve the performance..
How can you build an online multiplayer game, if the performance is so poor?

thanks!

Comment: I guess we need more infos. My experience with nodejs and websockets has been great so far. Never experienced any choppiness. So without any code we can only guess.

Comment: Check to see what method is being used for the communication. If websockets aren't working and it is failing over to something like jsonp, the jerking may be expected due to the interval between the update requests.

Comment: what transports are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `socket.send`, instead of `socket.emit`, and it sounds...better..not perfect but way better...

Answer (score -1):

There is probably jitter in the network traffic, which is normal, particularly for TCP traffic where the network guarantees in-order delivery, so that when one packet is late, all the others behind it have to wait.

I recommend you try it with UDP, with each datagram containing a delta in the X,Y position. That way, if a few packets are out of order, the mouse still gets to the same destination, and if a few packets are dropped then the other packets still come through and nudge the cursor along anyway.

Comment: UDP is a means of sending data over the internet, but which, unlike TCP, doesn't retry and guarantee in-order delivery of packets. Each has their advantages. If you're sending a file, use TCP. If you're sending real-time audio for VoIP, use UDP. Node.js is usually used with TCP, but supports UDP as well: http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html

Comment: Only problem is that browsers don't support UDP, at least not in any scriptable fashion.